# What is the proof of this Maxwell equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial H_{\phi}(r,t)}{\partial r}+\frac{H_{\phi}(r,t)}{r}=\frac{\partial D_z(r,t)}{\partial t}=\epsilon(r,E_z)\frac{\partial E_z(r,t)}{\partial t}$,

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial E_z(r,t)}{\partial r}=\mu_0\frac{\partial H_{\phi}(r,t)}{\partial t}$,

Comment: The Maxwell equations are laws of physics and thus cannot be mathematically proved, only experimentally tested and potentially falsified. If you want to prove them assuming some other physical laws, you'll need to state what laws you want to assume.

Answer (score 1):

This is another form of Maxwell's 4th equation. You can find the proof here : 
[Maxwell's Equation Proof](https://byjus.com/physics/maxwells-equations)